# inline-block object not resizing properly with dynamically sized image

Tags: html, image, css

I am trying to center a set of floated blocks that contain images that scale dynamically. However I am having an issue where the inline-block I am using to enter the floated blocks is not shrinking to the new size of the image. Instead it will wrap to the original size of the image, leaving a big empty space.

http://jsbin.com/ewonas/1/

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.inlineblock {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.constrainer {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.constrainer img {
    width: 100%;
}

<body>
    <div class="inlineblock">
        <div class="constrainer">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/500px-Smiley.svg.png">
            <h1>Product title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="constrainer">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/500px-Smiley.svg.png">
            <h1>Product title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can somebody please help me fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the width of the two `.constrainer` divs to `20%`. What this means is that the width is 20% of the parent `.inlineblock`. So when you have to two of them that adds up to 40% of the parent. That means you have 60% remaining, or space for another 3 `.constrainer` divs.

To make the `.inlineblock` element shrink down, you would need to set the width of the `.constrainer` divs to a number independent of its parent e.g. a fixed width like `300px` instead of a percentage.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ewonas/6